# Dlls to import in fastreport

Tags: winforms, dllimport, fastreport

I am using fastreport.net for reproting facility for winforms.

Now I have imported only one dll that is fastreport.dll in my project. And that was working fine. But if I run that project in others machine, that is not working. Because fastreport.bar.dll should be imported,if I import that dll in my project,then it works in other machines, but I came to know that there is no need of importing other dlls than fastreport.dll.

So is there need to import fastreport.bar.dll to import in my project, and I read in the manual that if I want to use docking window and all that then and then I will have need of import it ? Has anyone idea about that ?

Answer (score 1):

You may not import `FastReport.Bars.dll`, but you must distribute it i.e. copy it to the `.exe` folder or install it into the GAC on the client machine

Answer (score 1):

I see two referencies in FastReport.dll - FastReports.Bar and FastReport.Editor

These referencies could be stored into Global Assembly Cache (GAC). In that case they should work without import to your project.

So you may put these dlls to other machines into their GAC.

BTW, I don't know how does FR license allow this.